# Using an 8-way splitter, extract 1/12-th of something

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

I have a pile of dirt. And I have an 8 way splitter.

I can split into 8 and recombine splits as many times as I wish.

> What is the easiest run of splitting/combining I can do to pull out exactly 1/12th of the dirt?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Not possible. Every time you either split or sum, you end up with an element of $\Bbb Z[1/2]$, where the equation $12x=1$ does not have solution.

Comment: Think of it this way. You can split into $2^3$ parts, and recombine, so you can get powers of $2$. But you ask to get $12 = 2^2 \cdot 3$ parts. How will you get the division by $3$?

Comment: As an aside, please check to make sure you use relevant tags.  The tag "fair division" would be for problems like "I have three children and one slice of cake.  How can we design a pattern of cuts by the children so that no child feels like they got cheated in the size of their particular slice they receive?"  To be fair, the tools necessary to solve might not have been known to you at the time, but they are still the more relevant tags to use here.

Answer (score 3):

(*Not entirely serious, but too long for a comment*.)

There is no solution in the strict sense, as noted in the comments already, since any legal split or recombine leaves piles which are fractions having denominators that are powers of $2\,$. Therefore, it is not possible to isolate a pile of size $1/12$ in finitely many steps.

However, assuming one has enough time and patience to work through *infinitely* many steps, consider that division by $4$ is available as a split-by-$8$ followed by a recombine-$2\,$. Then, first split the whole pile by $4\,$, and set $1/4$ aside. Further split one of the remaining $1/4$ piles by $4$ and add it to the $1/4$ pile previously set aside. Repeat infinitely many times (or until the atoms of dirt no longer split ;-)), then the pile which collected all the intermediate splits will have a size of:

$$
\frac{1}{4}+\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^3 + \cdots \;=\; \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{1-\cfrac{1}{4}} \;=\; \frac{1}{3}
$$

Finally, divide that pile once more by $4$ to get $\;\displaystyle \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{12}\,$.

Comment: You can save the final division by $4$ if you just throw away three of the first four piles, and divide the remaining $1/4$ according to your algorithm here.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs You are right, of course, but I didn't worry much about optimizing the last step away, out of an infinity prior ;-)

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comments, this is not possible in a finite number of steps. However, you can approximate $1/12$ with arbitrary accuracy using $1/8$ divisions. To see how, let's write the fraction $1/12$ in its base-$8$ expansion:

$$\left(\frac1{12}\right)_8=0.0525252...$$

Thus, you can divide your original quantity into $\frac18$'s, divide one of those $\frac18$'s into $\frac1{8^2}$'s, and start with $5$ of those. To get closer, divide a remaining $\frac1{8^2}$ into $\frac1{8^3}$'s, and take $2$ of those. Continue until you're close enough!

Comment: Great approach!

Answer (score 0):

A classic move used in Factorio: take the output of two of the split belts and feed it back into the input, until the splitter runs "clean" (this is a thing that handles dirt though, so, uh, good luck).  At this point you're as close to $1/6$ in each pile as you can get.  Move the splitter, feed one of the little piles in, and four of the outputs together gives 1/12.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if this is the quickest, but was the most obvious to me.

1. Pound the splitter down:  you now have 8 piles of 1/8.
2. Combine three piles, then pound the splitter down. (this gives you 24s, seems like we're getting somewhere!)  Repeat this with another 3 piles.  You now have 16 piles of 1/24 and 2 piles of 1/8.
3. Combine the two piles of 1/8, with 3 piles of 1/24.  Pound the splitter down on that. You now have 24 piles of 1/24.
4. Combine two piles of 1/24 and you have your 1/12th.
5. Eat the dirt, for extra credit.  ;-)

Comment: After step 2 you actually have $3/64$ of the dirt in each pile.

Comment: It seems that you have posted answers here from several unregistered accounts (which explains why you were not able to edit this one - you were using a different account already). So probably registering would be a reasonable thing to do.